# Does matchMedia.js require respond.js to work in legacy IE browsers

Tags: javascript, media-queries, responsive-design

a question in my quest to line up handy tools for responsive web design --

The script [matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js) is written to enable tests such as the following for conditional loading of assets:

```
if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 480px)').matches) {
  // run small-screen related dom scripting
}
```

Will this script do its job in IE 6-8 without the help of [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to force these browsers to respond to media queries, or does it require the help of respond.js?

Its source is short and located at the github repository linked above.

Answer (score 2):

If a browser does not natively support media queries, matchMedia will always return false (even when using respond.js).